# Plotting specific columns of multiple Datasets on one Master Plot

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

I have four datasets, a sample can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/byxx5wv2ci5iaqr/Ratio_J_B5H2.csv), all of them have four columns and same column names. But I just want to plot 1st column on x axis and last column on y axis, and I want to plot all of them on one Master plot on four equal areas, 
like the image below.

How can I achieve that ?

[image]
<sub>(source: [nps.gov](https://science.nature.nps.gov/im/datamgmt/statistics/r/images/graphics_ex/hist4.png))</sub>
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution using `par`.

(I read your file `Ratio_J_B5H2.csv` into R as data frame `dat`.)

Create a 2 x 2 window for the plots:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
```

Now, you could create four plots:

```
barplot(dat[,4], names.arg = dat[,1])
barplot(dat[,4], names.arg = dat[,1])
barplot(dat[,4], names.arg = dat[,1])
barplot(dat[,4], names.arg = dat[,1])
```

[image]

Comment: @ sven, I'm trying to show values of each bar with this command;`a<-barplot(Ratio_J_B5H2[,2], names.arg = Ratio_J_B5H2[,1],xlab="PLAYERS", ylab="Unsuccessful Passes",main="Unsuccessful Passes, Team 5, Half 2")` and then `text` command:`text(a, 0, round(Ratio_J_B5H2, 1),cex=1,pos=3)`, but I'm getting this error: `non-numeric variable in data frame: JN`
, where am I wrong ?

Comment: @forochelian The type of the values in column `JN` is not numeric. You have to tranform it to numeric using `Ratio_J_B5H2$JN <- as.numeric(Ratio_J_B5H2$JN)`. Then your command would work. But I suppose you will be surprised by the result...

Comment: @ yeah, it didn't work either, I just want to show the "Success Ratio"[Column 4 in data, y axis on the plot] values on the bars, but I just couldn't. Can you help me out ?

Comment: @forochelian `a<-barplot(Ratio_J_B5H2[,2], 
           names.arg = Ratio_J_B5H2[,1],xlab="PLAYERS", 
           ylab="Unsuccessful Passes",main="Unsuccessful Passes, Team 5, Half 2",
           ylim = c(0, max(Ratio_J_B5H2[,2])+5)); 


text(a, Ratio_J_B5H2[,2]+.4, round(as.numeric(Ratio_J_B5H2$JN), 1),cex=1,pos=3)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good, simple resource for multiple plots:

http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

Also check `?layout`
And `?par`